# Convert float32 array to datetime64 in Numpy 1.6.1

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

What is the proper way of converting integer dates to datetime64 in numpy? I tried:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([20090913, 20101020, 20110125])
numpy.datetime64(a.astype("S8"))
```

but get an incorrect conversion. How about reading them in correctly as numpy.datetime64 objects using numpy.loadtxt (they are coming from a csv file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oddly, this works: `numpy.datetime64(a.astype("S8").tolist())`, while this does not:   `numpy.datetime64(a.astype("S8"))`. The first method is still a bit less convoluted than: `numpy.array([numpy.datetime64(str(i)) for i in a])`. I asked why in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709824/numpy-datetime64-dtype-oddity).

Answer (score 5):

You problem is that `datetime64` expects a string in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, while the type conversion produces strings in the format `yyyymmdd`. I would suggest something like this:

```
conversion = lambda x: "%s-%s-%s" % (x[:4], x[4:6], x[6:])
np_conversion = numpy.frompyfunc(conversion,1,1)
b = np_conversion(a.astype('S10'))
numpy.datetime64(b)
```

However it's not working for me (I have numpy 1.6.1), it fails with the message "NotImplementedError: Not implemented for this type". Unless that is implemented in 1.7, I can only suggest a pure Python solution:

```
numpy.datetime64(numpy.array([conversion(str(x)) for x in a], dtype="S10"))
```

...or pre-processing your input, to deliver the dates in the expected format.

**Edit:** I can also offer an alternative solution, using `vectorize`, but I don't know very well how it works, so I don't know what's going wrong:

```
>>> conversion = vectorize(lambda x: "%s-%s-%s" % (x[:4], x[4:6], x[6:]), otypes=['S10'])
>>> conversion(a.astype('S10'))
array(['2009', '2010', '2011'],
      dtype='|S4')
```

For some reason it's ignoring the `otypes` and outputting `|S4` instead of `|S10`. Sorry I can't help more, but this should provide a starting point for searching other solutions.

**Update:** Thanks to OP feedback, I thought of a new possibility. This should work as expected:

```
>>> conversion = lambda x: numpy.datetime64(str(x))
>>> np_conversion = numpy.frompyfunc(conversion, 1, 1)
>>> np_conversion(a)
array([2009-09-13 00:00:00, 2010-10-20 00:00:00, 2011-01-25 00:00:00], dtype=object)

# Works too:
>>> conversion = lambda x: numpy.datetime64("%s-%s-%s" % (x/10000, x/100%100, x%100))
```

Weird how, in this case, `datetime64` works fine with or without the dashes...

Comment: +1 from me; your first solution seems to work just fine for me (NumPy 2.0 dev).

Comment: I'm wondering why numpy.datetime64('20090921') works, if the required format is with dashes?

Comment: @Benjamin really strange... But your comment gave me a new idea, try my updated answer, worked fine for me.

Comment: So basically, numpy.array([numpy.datetime64(str(i)) for i in a]). I was wondering if there was a more direct way than this, however.

Comment: @Benjamin: What do you mean with a more direct way? Directly while reading your data from a csv/text file?

Comment: I mean that doing a type conversion should not require a list comprehension. There must be a better way.